# A warning says couldn't find the URI of href attribute in address tag in jsp file while running a web-service

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets, soap

When I'm trying to run a web service on localhost Apache tomcat server it gives me the warning in the jsp file "src/main/webapp/services not found".

And an error while launching the tomcat:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException.

are these both issues related, can anyone tell me what's the issue with warning in the jsp file.

Index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>
      <!-- here is the warning --> 
        Welcome to the Customer Orders Service - <a href="services">Available
            Services</a>
    </h2>

</body>
</html>
```

cxf-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <jaxws:endpoint id="customerOrderid" address="/customerOrders"
        wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/customerOrders.wsdl" implementor="com.bharath.ws.train.imp.CustomersOrdersWS"
        serviceName="customersOrders:CustomerOrdersService" xmlns:customersOrders="http://train.ws.bharath.com/" >
        </jaxws:endpoint>
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging /> 
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Image for the project directory structure: [image: project directory structure]

Comment: The warning is because your `href` has a relative location which means that it tries to find `services` in the same location as the `index.jsp` file, in `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: So, if i run it on a server then will the <url-pattern> in web.xml take care of that. @tima.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jaxws, but in general to access a service you have to use a URL in this format: `/<web app context root>/<service url or pattern>`. So I don't think your link will work.

Comment: Any idea regarding this error :  tomcat: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException. Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/firstws]] @tima

Comment: The above error:  "tomcat: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException." was resolved after replacing a .jar file (may be was a corrupted jar file). There was warning while maven install about that .jar (which i ignored earlier, shouldn't have done that).